# Multiples Program

Tags: java, algorithm, math

Here is the programming problem i am trying to solve: 2520 is the smallest number that can be divided by each of the numbers from 1 to 10 without any remainder.

What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?

Here is my solution so far, however the answer comes up as zero everytime so i think i have an error in my code. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public static boolean isDiv(int num){
    boolean isDiv = false;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++){
        if (i == 20){

            isDiv = true;

        }
        if ((num % i) == 0){
            continue;

        }
        else  {
            break;
        }

    }


return isDiv;}

public static int smallMulti(int num){
    boolean div = isDiv(num);
    int answer = 0;

    for (int i = num; num < 2520; i--){

        if (div = true){
            answer = i;
        }
    }

return answer;}
```

Comment: because it´s most likely not in the range of `Integer.MIN_VALUE-2520`, which is the range you are checking.

Comment: No, you're not. `num < 2520; i--`. You're most likely not doing a single iteration.

Comment: Acutally you loop until `i` overflows negative and is equal to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. you also never reassign `div`.

Comment: for (int i = num; num < 2520; i--){

        if (div = true){
            answer = i;
        }
    } is full of problems. Check it.

Comment: This is not effective. You need to compute lcm (Least common multiple), check this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple#Computing_the_least_common_multiple

Comment: `if (div = true)` Please recheck your Java book about comparing stuff.

Comment: As Tom said, div = true is absolutely wrong. You're assigning div true. What you tried is div == true, and even that is reduntant as div is already boolean. Just type in div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overcomplicating the whole problem, combined with multiple logical mistakes. Basicly you just need 2 loops. Here´s a the code checking for the first number beeing devisible by every number until `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. If you want to go higher you could adopt the code to work with `long`.

```
public static int smallMulti(int num) {
    for (int i = 1; num <= Integer.MAX_VALUE; ++i) { // Check every int in the scope of the Integer
        for (int j = 2;j<=num;++j) {
            if(i % j != 0) {
                break; // If i % j is unequal to 0 then this number isn´t valid.
            }
            if(j == num) {
                return i; // If we reached j == num then everything was divisble yet so we can return i as the correct value;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Heres the example output for this main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i = 2; i <= 20; ++i)
        System.out.println("Smallest Value divisible by 1-"+ i + " = " + smallMulti(i));
}
```

OutPut

```
Smallest Value divisible by 1-2 = 2
Smallest Value divisible by 1-3 = 6
Smallest Value divisible by 1-4 = 12
Smallest Value divisible by 1-5 = 60
Smallest Value divisible by 1-6 = 60
Smallest Value divisible by 1-7 = 420
Smallest Value divisible by 1-8 = 840
Smallest Value divisible by 1-9 = 2520
Smallest Value divisible by 1-10 = 2520
Smallest Value divisible by 1-11 = 27720
Smallest Value divisible by 1-12 = 27720
Smallest Value divisible by 1-13 = 360360
Smallest Value divisible by 1-14 = 360360
Smallest Value divisible by 1-15 = 360360
Smallest Value divisible by 1-16 = 720720
Smallest Value divisible by 1-17 = 12252240
Smallest Value divisible by 1-18 = 12252240
Smallest Value divisible by 1-19 = 232792560
Smallest Value divisible by 1-20 = 232792560
```

Answer (score 2):

I implemented with lcm(least common multiple)

```
public static int lcm(int a, int b) {
    return (a*b)/gcd(a, b);
}

public static int gcd(int a, int b) {
    return b == 0 ? a : gcd(b, a % b);
}

public static int smallMulti(int n) {
    int number = 1;

    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        number = lcm(number, i);
    }

    return number;
}
```